# Add hours or minutes(randomly generated) in 24 hour format time python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime

I have a 24 hour format lets 10:00:00 now I want to randomly generate hours range(1 to 2.5) and add it in a my 24 hour format 10:00:00.
e.g

```
random_hour=0.30 // how I can generate time randomly
24_hour_format=24_hour_format+random_hour  // result should be 10:30:00
```

I have tried I have used

```
 timespent=random.uniform(1.0,2.5)
 random_hour="{:.1f}".format(timespent)
 24_hour_format=24_hour_format+random_hour
```

but it gives me 10:00:00.1.4 // if random number is 1.4  how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make use of `datetime.timedelta`. In this case you should do the following:

```py
import datetime
import random

random_hour = random.uniform(1, 2.5)
given_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

new_time = given_time + datetime.timedelta(hours=random_hour)

print(new_time.isoformat())
```

Comment: timespent=random.uniform(1.0,2.5)
             random_hour="{:.1f}".format(timespent)   i am getting problem in this,its showing can only concatenate str (not "datetime.timedelta") to str

Comment: I have updated my code in question can you check it again?

Comment: I've expanded the example in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strftime()` (from **datetime**) method to convert to any desired format and print.
[hope this link will help](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime)